# How to add a line in code for ruby

Tags: ruby

I apologise I am sure the answer is out there but I simply cannot articulate it well enough for google search..

Given a long piece of code

```
puts 'This is a really long line of ruby code here'
```

How can you separate it over 2 lines, i.e.

```
puts 'This is a really long
      line of ruby code here'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'first line'\
  ' second line'\
  ' third line'

puts str
```